# Why is ROS_DISTRO not set for rolling?

Tags: ros2

After sourcing a rolling install, the environment variable ROS_DISTRO is not set. Is this intentional?

```
tyler@fractal:~$ source /opt/ros/rolling/setup.bash
tyler@fractal:~$ echo $ROS_DISTRO

tyler@fractal:~$
```

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! 
As @JRTG said, the `$ROS_DISTRO` is set for rolling as well. I have confirmed it. I wonder if you are using any custom package or shell? Can you please confirm that the `$ echo $0` and `$ echo $SHELL` commands return you `bash` and `/bin/bash` respectively. Also, what does `printenv | grep -i ros` say?

Comment: `echo $0` returns `bash`.  `echo $SHELL` returns `/bin/bash`

Comment: The env command returns a bunch of things, which include many variables, just not ROS_DISTRO. Here are some of them: ```ROS_VERSION=2
ROS_PYTHON_VERSION=3
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/tyler/code/ws_moveit/install/rsl/share
ROS_DOMAIN_ID=29
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be something on your side, as it works for me both with a non-recently updated source tree, as well as with a fresh `vcs import`:

```
$ echo $ROS_DISTRO

$ source install/setup.bash 
$ echo $ROS_DISTRO
rolling
```

It also works using packages:

- Pull [22.04 Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/ubuntu/22.04/images/sha256-ffa841e85005182836d91f7abd24ec081f3910716096955dcc1874b8017b96c9?context=explore)
- Install ROS2 Rolling per [the official instructions](https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debians.html) (package `ros-rolling-ros-base`),

```
root@664088dbb40c:/# echo $ROS_DISTRO

root@664088dbb40c:/# source /opt/ros/rolling/setup.bash 
root@664088dbb40c:/# echo $ROS_DISTRO
rolling
root@664088dbb40c:/#
```

EDIT: added following `grep` output:

```
/opt/ros2_rolling/install$ grep -rI ROS_DISTRO
lib/python3.10/site-packages/rpyutils/import_c_library.py:        distro = os.environ.get('ROS_DISTRO', 'rolling')
lib/python3.10/site-packages/ros2doctor/api/package.py:    distro_name = os.environ.get('ROS_DISTRO')
lib/python3.10/site-packages/ros2doctor/api/package.py:        doctor_error('ROS_DISTRO is not set.')
lib/python3.10/site-packages/ros2doctor/api/platform.py:    Check ROS_DISTRO environment variables and distribution installed.
lib/python3.10/site-packages/ros2doctor/api/platform.py:    distro_name = os.environ.get('ROS_DISTRO')
lib/python3.10/site-packages/ros2doctor/api/platform.py:        doctor_error('ROS_DISTRO is not set.')
share/ros_environment/package.xml:  <description>The package provides the environment variables `ROS_VERSION` and `ROS_DISTRO`.</description>
share/ros_environment/environment/1.ros_distro.dsv:set;ROS_DISTRO;rolling
share/ros_environment/environment/0.ros_distro_check.sh:if [ -n "$ROS_DISTRO" -a "$ROS_DISTRO" != "rolling" ]; then
share/ros_environment/environment/0.ros_distro_check.sh:  echo "ROS_DISTRO was set to '$ROS_DISTRO' before. Please make sure that the environment does not mix paths from different distributions." >&2
share/ros_environment/environment/1.ros_distro.sh:export ROS_DISTRO=rolling
```

Comment: I'm testing this on ubuntu 22.04 with rolling installed via debians. I've done an apt update/upgrade today.

Comment: Also works in a docker container, see updated answer.

Comment: The docker containers define the ROS_DISTRO environment variable themselves.

Comment: No, the _ROS_ docker containers set the ROS_DISTRO variable. As written in my answer: I pulled the _Ubuntu 22.04_ docker (i.e. not related to ROS). I then installed rolling into that docker using `apt-get` (per the official instructions). It works just fine. I still conclude that it is something on your setup.

Comment: Furthermore: the ROS docker has the ROS_DISTRO variable set even before sourcing the setup.bash file. As you can see in my answer in the Ubuntu docker the variable is not set until sourcing.

Comment: I don't understand then. I also tested in a docker container, and it seems to work as you state. I'll assume something is broken locally but that still leaves me confused. I also have Iron and Humble installed and they do not have this behavior.

Comment: I did a grep in the install directory, see the edited answer. It seems that ROS_DISTRO is set by the `ros_environment` package. Is it installed?

Comment: I finally figured this out. What happened was I installed rolling through rosdep install (only the dependencies of the packages I was building) and none of them depend on ros_enviroment. After installing `ros-rolling-desktop` the problem is fixed. I'm sorry for the noise, hopefully if someone else hits this they will know they just need to install something.